# Is there a way I can get the country info (code) from the flag selected in react-phone-input-2/material-ui-phone-number

Tags: reactjs

I am using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number package which is developed from react-phone-input package and want to get the country code base don the flag selected from drop down. Is that possible? I do see details about object 'country', but I am unable to get country code.

```
<MuiPhoneNumber value={phone || ''} defaultCountry={'us'}  preferredCountries={['gb', 'us']} disableAreaCodes={true} value={phone || ''} onChange={handleOnChange} />
```

I am able to get just the target value in onChange

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the **supported events** in [material-ui-phone-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number#supported-events)

```
<MuiPhoneNumber onChange={(value, country) => console.log(country)} />
```

The second parameter will give you a country data object which includes: **name, dialCode, country code**.

Also

> Country data object not returns from onKeyDown event

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself and figured this out...

```
{<MuiPhoneNumber value={phone || ''} defaultCountry={'us'}  preferredCountries={['gb', 'us']} disableAreaCodes={true} value={phone || ''} onChange={(country) => handleOnChange(country.countryCode)} />}
```

just pass country to the onchange and use country.countryCode to get the code, or country.name to get name and country.dialCode to get the dial code.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it:

```
 const handlePhoneNumber=(phoneInfo) =>{
    let PhoneNumberWithCode = phoneInfo[0];
    let {dialCode} = phoneInfo[1];
     // the rest of the code 
    }
    
 <MuiPhoneNumber fullWidth name="phone_number"            
   disableAreaCodes={true}  // so that only one country code per country is displayed
   value={formData.phone_number}                                          
   onChange={(...phoneInfo)=>handlePhoneNumber(phoneInfo)}
   />
```

When I used

```
onChange={(value, country)=>handlePhoneNumber(value, country)}
```

I kept getting the following error:

```
Type '(value: any, country: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> & ((e: string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void)'.
```