# How to get selected country code in material-ui-phone-number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, libphonenumber

In order to let users input phone number, I am using a package called [material-ui-phone-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number). Now the issue is that I want to get the country code for it in order to check that whether user has entered a 0 after the country code or not and based on that I have to decide the allowed length for the number.

I did some research and found out this question and tried its response:[Is there a way I can get the country info (code) from the flag selected in react-phone-input-2/material-ui-phone-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461383/is-there-a-way-i-can-get-the-country-info-code-from-the-flag-selected-in-react)

In my case the onChange event gives an error as it has only one parameter which can be seen in the image as well:
[image: material-ui-phonenumber-class]

My code:

```
                    <MuiPhoneNumber
                        id="phone"
                        name="phone"
                        value={props.phone}
                        defaultCountry={'gb'}
                        onChange={(value) => props.setPhone(value)}
                        onKeyPress={(event) => validateAndSetPhoneNumber(event)}
                        variant='outlined'
                        label='Your Phone number'
                        required
                        countryCodeEditable={false}
                        enableLongNumbers
                        disableAreaCodes
                    />
```

Kindly help me in achieving what I want or if there is anything I am doing wrong?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `allDetails` to get the country code -

```
onChange={(val, allDetails) => {
   // val contains the phoneNumber
   // allDetails contains countryCode, dialCode and name of the country
   console.log(allDetails)
}}
```